# Aligning a Table body based on the Header

Tags: css

I am trying to align elements of table along with its header. I have divided table head and body into two components (As I want to operate operations of Header, keeping body unaffected). Here is how it looks:
[image]

Although the two entities are different, is there any way to align and reserve body space according to the headers. Like for example, advertiser column elements should be center aligned to its header. Here is the link to reproduce in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-snowflake-g2j14?file=/public/src/App.js).

If it cannot be done by segregating the two is there any other way? Currently I am importing input from an array with first element [a,b,c,d] as header and rest all of them as body.

Here is my css class:

```
.HeadElems, .BodyElems
{
    border-left: 2 px solid black;
    padding: 0 1%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


.HeadElems:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.Head
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0.2% 10%;
    background-color: #41aea9;
    width: 80%;
}

.BodyRow
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 10%;
    background-color: #e8ffff;
    width: 80%;  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .Head, .BodyRow {
      margin: 0.2% 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `table` to be displayed, I should suggest you to use the `table` HTML Element that totally suits your requisite.

And you can easily center the text by doing a little bit of CSS:

```
th, td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: acually react throws me a warning saying th is not a part of table.

Comment: Yes, because you have to wrap all those table tags inside `<table>`. More about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table